# SQL : How to state that no element of a set can be present in another set?

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

Suppose I have this database scheme:

[image: schema]

I've been stumbling on this question for more than one hour: 
"Select all albums of which no track has been used in a playlist".

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT parentalbum.albumid FROM album AS parentalbum 
  INNER JOIN track 
    ON track.albumid = parentalbum.albumid 
  INNER JOIN playlistitem
    ON track.trackid = playlistitem.trackid            // Join the 3 tables
  WHERE NOT ((SELECT track.trackid FROM album 
                INNER JOIN track
                  ON album.albumid = track.albumid
                WHERE track.albumid = parentalbum.albumid ) // Select songs from one album
            IN playlistitem.trackid   )                   // Check if at least one element of the album is in a playlist? (faulty)
```

My query is probably completely wrong, so I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I am asked to solve this using correlated subqueries. Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS()` is the answer:

```
SELECT *        -- Select all albums
FROM album a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (      -- of which no track
    SELECT * FROM track t
    WHERE t.albumid = a.albumid
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM playlistitem pi   -- has been used in a playlist
        WHERE pi.trackid = t.trackid    
        )
    )
        ;
```

---

Even simpler:

```
SELECT *        -- Select all albums
FROM album a    
WHERE NOT EXISTS (      -- of which no track
        SELECT * 
        FROM track t    -- has been used in a playlist
        JOIN playlistitem pi ON t.trackid = pi.trackid
        WHERE t.albumid = a.albumid 
        )
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join` to connect the tables loosly. Then group by the albums and take only those having zero tracks in the `playlistitem` table

```
select a.id, a.title
from album a
left join track t on t.albumid = a.albumid
left join playlistitem pi on pi.trackid = t.trackid
group by a.id, a.title
having sum(case when pi.trackid is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, however the exercise specifically asks to use correlated subqueries (will edit the question) - how could I solve it in that manner?

Answer (score 0):

First create a subquery which has an inner join to join together all results that are connected in track and playlistitem. Then check if the albumid is not in that list. I used the distinct to get only unique values of the albumid in the subquery.

```
SELECT a.albumid
FROM album a
WHERE a.albumid NOT IN 
(  SELECT DISTINCT t.albumid
   FROM track t
   INNER JOIN playlistitem p
   ON p.trackid = t.trackid
)
```

Comment: Sadly, it seems that this answer doesn't use a correlated subquery, which is what was requested.

Comment: True, if correlated subqueries is necessary then the best answer would be to use NOT EXISTS() as stated in the other answer.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function - putting a column between parentheses is totally useless

Answer (score 0):

Alternate version which uses correlated subquery but doesn't use `NOT EXISTS`, just because...

```
Select a.*
  From Album As a
  Where 0 = (
    Select Count(*)
      From PlaylistItem As pi
      Join Track As t on pi.TrackID = t.TrackID
      Where t.AlbumID = a.AlbumID);
```